# Target must not be null using Picasso Library

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, picasso

I implemented a `listView` using the Picasso Library 2.4.0 and I'm facing an issue. What happens: I launch the app using Android Studio, then I go to the specific fragment on which I implemented the `listView`, everything looks ok ( all images are being loaded, same for the `TextView`) BUT if I try to scroll down the app crashes. This is what it tells me:

```
2-03 19:45:38.290  31501-31501/com.zenyt E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:553)
            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:536)
            at com.zenyt.Volvo.Volvo1$SampleListViewAdapter.getView(Volvo1.java:106)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2445)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:642)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5525)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3413)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3901)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7337)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2410)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2145)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2115)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1468)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2063)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7520)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4402)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4380)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4452)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4503)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711
```

It points me to this line: `at com.zenyt.Volvo.Volvo1$SampleListViewAdapter.getView(Volvo1.java:106)`
which is: `Picasso.with(context)`

```
 public final class SampleListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final Context context;
        private final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> models = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> price = new ArrayList<>();
        public SampleListViewAdapter (Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            Collections.addAll(urls, Data.Volvo1URLS);
            Collections.addAll(models, Data.VolvoModels);
            Collections.addAll(price, Data.VolvoPrice);
        }

        @Override public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            ViewHolder holder1;
            if (view == null) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_list_detail_item, parent, false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder1 = new ViewHolder();

                holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
                holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url);
                holder1.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);

                view.setTag(holder);
                view.setTag(holder1);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                holder1 = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            // Get the image URL for the current position.
            String url = getItem(position);
            String models = getItem1(position);
            String price = getItem2(position);

            holder.text.setText(models);
            holder.text.setTextSize(16);

            holder1.text.setText(price);
            holder1.text.setTextSize(16);

            // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.error)
                    .resizeDimen(R.dimen.list_detail_image_size, R.dimen.list_detail_image_size)
                    .centerInside()
                    .tag(context)
                    .into(holder.image);

            return view;
        }

        @Override public int getCount() {
            return urls.size();
        }

        @Override public String getItem(int position) {
            return urls.get(position);
        }
        private String getItem1(int position) {
            return models.get(position);
        }
        private String getItem2(int position) {
            return price.get(position);
        }

        @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

         class ViewHolder {
            ImageView image;
            TextView text;
        }
    }
```

The app was working fine until I added a second `holder` -> `holder1`. If I remove all lines that belong to this `holder1` the app works with with no problem.

The sample_list_detail_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_detail_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_detail_image_size"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/url"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: It probably is `image` of `holder1` because you never initialize that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because `holder.image` is null - and `into()` specifically checks that the argument you pass in is not null.

When you use `setTag()`/`getTag()`, only a single object can be stored. Therefore when you call

```
view.setTag(holder);
view.setTag(holder1);
```

None of the data in `holder` is saved - it is replaced with `holder1`. Instead of having multiple `ViewHolder`, you should just add another field to your existing `ViewHolder` class:

```
class ViewHolder {
  ImageView image;
  TextView url;
  TextView price;
}
```

Then you can use just a single `ViewHolder`:

```
holder = new ViewHolder();

holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
holder.url = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url);
holder.price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);

view.setTag(holder);
```

Comment: Mission complete! :) Thank you!

Comment: you given me an idea.Thank you