# Error: Target must not be null picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

I am getting error: Target must not be null Picasso

```
public void getListFromDb(){
    Cursor res = myDb.ViewAll();
    startManagingCursor(res);


    //Map cursor from db to viewFields
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4, DatabaseHelper.COL_5};
    int[] toViewIDS = new int[]{R.id.viewName, R.id.viewAddress, R.id.viewPostcode, R.id.viewType};

    //Create SimpleCursorAdaptor with null cursor
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, null, fromFieldNames, toViewIDS, 0);
    // Set adaptor for listView
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdaptor);

    Picasso
            .with(getApplicationContext())
            .load("http://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg")
            .resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel). does not respect aspect ratio
            .into(img);




    new AsyncTask<SimpleCursorAdapter, Void, Cursor>() {
        private SimpleCursorAdapter mSimpleCursorAdapter;
        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(SimpleCursorAdapter... params) {
            // Save cursorAdapter to use in postExecute
            this.mSimpleCursorAdapter = params[0];
            // Load cursor on background thread with search function
            return myDb.ViewAll();


            }
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
            super.onPostExecute(cursor);
            // and update the cursor (which is already in the listview)
            this.mSimpleCursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
        }
    }.execute(myCursorAdaptor);




}

private void registerListClickCallback() {
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long IDinDB) {
            Cursor res = myDb.GetRow(IDinDB);
            if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                long idDB = res.getLong(DatabaseHelper.ROWID);
                String message = "ID: " + idDB;
                //Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String hello = Long.toString(idDB);

                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewActivity.this, ImageFullViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ImgID", hello);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

How do I solve this issue.
Also, the url of the image is just temporary as I'm using it for testing. Will I be able to insert the Real Path of the image inside .load() ?

Thanks

Comment: `into(img)` may be ImageView is null

Comment: how can imageView be null, it works fine with the adaptor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target must not be null using Picasso Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305582/target-must-not-be-null-using-picasso-library)